# A rat in a maze using stacks

Tags: c, loops, stack

```
 - mark[1,0]=1; top=1; stack[top].row=1; stack[top].col=0;   
   stack[top].dir=1; while (top>0) {
       loc = pop();
       cr=loc.row; cc=loc.col; cd=loc.dir;
       while (cd <= 4) {
            nr=cr+move[cd].r;  nc=cc+move[cd].c;
            if (nr==grow && nc==gcol) {
                 for(i=0; i<=top; i++) printLoc(stack[i]);
                 print(cr, cc); print(grow, gcol);
                 return;
            }
            if (maze[nr][nc]==0 && mark[nr][nc]==0) {
                 mark[nr][nc] = 1;
                 loc.row=cr; loc.col=cc; loc.dir=cd+1;
                 push(loc);
                 cr=nr; cc=nc; cd=1;
            }
            else cd=cd+1;
       } } print(“no path in maze”);
```

I've been looking at this algorithm for about an hour but still can't understand it.
I understand that col/row/direction = column, row, direction, and mark means a 2-dimensional array. But I can't get how to implement this algorithm and turn it into code since I can't understand how it works.
Could someone explain this algorithm, please?

More info: 1 = 0,1(move right), 2 = 1,0(move down), 3 = 0, -1(move left), 4 = -1,0(move up). To store the path use stack. If you use stack choose depth-first search, if you use queue choose breadth-first search. 1 is the blocked path while 0 is the path you can walk on.

Comment: Considering that the pseudo-code is already very C-like then it shouldn't too hard to basically copy-paste it into a source file. Although if you don't understand the algorithm or the code itself, that will make you a [cargo cult programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which isn't good. Where did you find this pseudo-code? What documentation is related to the code where you found it? What pother resource do you have about the problem and possible solutions?

Comment: Trying to figure out this code without any extra information is a major pain. I.e. `maze` contains zero and non-zero values, but it's not explicit what the two mean. One is "allowed", the other "disallowed", but if we have to figure everything out its going to take us a lot of time. What have you been told, and what have you figured out yourself? You can't just stare at an algorithm and expect to suddenly understand all of it.

Comment: 1 = 0,1(move right), 2 = 1,0(move down), 3 = 0, -1(move left), 4 = -1,0(move up). To store the path use stack. If you use stack choose depth-first search, if you use queue choose breadth-first search.  1 is the blocked path while 0 is the path you can walk on. That's everything I could translate. I'm an exchanged student studying in a language that i'm not fluent in so understanding programming without understanding professor is a little bit hard.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what your main goal is: a) _to implement this algorithm and turn it into code_, or b) to _understand how it works._